# Getting Active Directory user in C#

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have built a C# application to get users from AD. It works fine.

The problem I have is that when new users are added in a specific server then my app does not retrieve them. Users that have been added in the past (a few months ago) are retrieved.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It depends on your code and the structure of active directory. For example you may read users of a specific domain or OU of a domain, but new users added to a different OU or even different domain.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have multiple active directory servers. When you add a new user to a domain they have to sync each other. This happens every 60min normally. Otherwise you have to ask all active directories and merge the information.

Comment: Looks like it is something like that but it is not the 60min sync because there are users that have been added several days ago and they are not displayed. Any link on how to ask all active directories to merge the information?

Comment: I suggest that in your C# code you ask a specific domain server, right? You have to get a list of all domain servers and fetch them all.

Comment: What I do is get the domains of the current forest

Comment: ..continue the above .. Forest currentForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
                DomainCollection myDomains = currentForest.Domains;

Comment: Fetch the DomainCollection.

Comment: That is what I am doing with DomainCollection myDomains = currentForest.Domains; Isn't it?

Comment: Domain controller replicates changes with its replication partners every few seconds by default. domain controllers in different sites replicate changes every 3 hours by default. I'd recommend to open ADUC on the server, which your program connects to query AD and try to find added users on the server. If users persist, there's something with your code.